# Как cохранить и загрузить настройки из Memo в INI?

Tags: delphi

Настройки сохраняются из Memo, но загружается только первая строка из 3 сохраненных. Что я делаю не так ?

```
procedure T_Main.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Ini: Tinifile;
begin
  Ini := TiniFile.Create(extractfilepath(paramstr(0))+'Setting.ini');
  Ini.WriteString('settings_p','T1', Memo1.Lines[0]); //сохраняем в ини
  Ini.WriteString('settings_p','T2', Memo1.Lines[1]); //сохраняем в ини
  Ini.WriteString('settings_p','T3', Memo1.Lines[2]); //сохраняем в ини
  Ini.Free;
end;

procedure T_Main.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Ini: Tinifile;
begin
  Ini := TiniFile.Create(extractfilepath(paramstr(0))+'Setting.ini');
  Memo1.Lines[0] := Ini.ReadString('settings_p','T1',Memo1.Lines[0]); //загружаем из ини
  Memo1.Lines[1] := Ini.ReadString('settings_p','T2',Memo1.Lines[1]); //загружаем из ини
  Memo1.Lines[2] := Ini.ReadString('settings_p','T3',Memo1.Lines[2]); //загружаем из ини
  Ini.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, Татьяна. А в `Memo1` сколько строк в момент вызова `Button2Click`? Как Вы определили, что строки не загружаются?

Comment: Igor, Здравствуйте. Исправила вопрос. Получается загружается только первая строка из 3 сохраненных. В момент вызова memo пустой.

Comment: Татьяна, учитесь пожалуйста нормально форматировать код, чтобы не было винегрета из отступов ..

Comment: Kromster, Замечание принято. В дальнейшем это правило будет соблюдено.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure T_Main.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Ini: TIniFile;
begin
  Ini := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Setting.ini');
  try
    Memo1.Lines.Clear;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Ini.ReadString('settings_p', 'T1', ''); //загружаем из ини  
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Ini.ReadString('settings_p', 'T2', ''); //загружаем из ини
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Ini.ReadString('settings_p', 'T3', ''); //загружаем из ини
  finally
    Ini.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Теперь работает отлично. Я кстати про очистку Memo1.Lines.Clear; чего то тоже не подумала. Хотя и знала про это. Igor, Как всегда, Вам - огромное спасибо.